# Inequality proof withy infinite sum

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis, inequality, proof-writing

If $0<p\le 1$ then prove that the following inequality holds:

$\displaystyle \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|a_i+b_i|^p\le \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|a_i|^p+\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}|b_i|^p.$

I know that this inequality with finite sum is true but I don't know the proof. Also the proof is trivial for $p=1$. But I'm unable to find a proof for $p<1$.  Can anyone suggest me how to prove it or can anyone give some source of the proof ?

Comment: Do you know the Holder inequality? Usual proof of Minkowsky inequality (in your question, you can try to google it) is based on Holder

Comment: Use $\lvert a+b\rvert^p \leqslant (\lvert a\rvert + \lvert b\rvert)^p \leqslant \lvert a\rvert^p + \lvert b\rvert^p$.

Comment: @DominikKutek I know Holder's inequality but I don't think it is based on Holder.

Comment: If you know the inequality for finite sums, try to deduce this one by taking limits.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I've misread, for $p \in (1,\infty)$ its based on Holder. Case $ p \in (0,1)$ is easier

Answer (score 0):

The map $x\mapsto x^p$ defined on $[0,\infty)$ is concave for $0<p\le1$ and it sends $0$ to $0$. Therefore it is subadditive. Moreover, the map is increasing because $p>0$. Therefore $$\lvert a_i+b_i\rvert\le (\lvert a_i\rvert+\lvert b_i\rvert)^p\le \lvert a_i\rvert^p+\lvert b_i\rvert^p$$